# control a Qt/C++/QML GUI application running on a embedded device from a remote client application?

Tags: c++, qt, vnc, qtwebchannel, qtremoteobjects

**Scenario:** 
We have a Qt application(Qt 5.9.5,C++,QML,Ubuntu) running on a device (deals with telecommunications), which can also be viewed in a browser using webserver. All the operations done manually on the device have been visualized on the browser simultaneously.

**Requirement:** Now what we want to achieve is build a similar application(maybe web application) so that you execute it from a browser and simultaneously the application on the device should execute by itself. The device is just switched on initially. everything should be operated from the client application. What are the possible options?

We have started with Qt **Remoteobjects** to make a remote application but Qt version of device is older one when compared with Qt version of some functionalities in remote objects module. so using remote objects is not possible now.

Can **Qt WebGL** streaming helpful in this case?

Does **QtWebchannel** and **websockets** help by setting up communication with **html/javascript** application. Is it a possible solution?

Is virtual network computing (**VNC**) an option to think about in my scenario?

I have come across some concepts like Qt for **WebAssembly**, Web toolkit(**Wt**), **Emscripten**, **Cutelyst** web-framework, **Qt for Automation - MQTT,OPC UA, KNX, CoAP** . Do these really help at any point while developing a client application to control the **QML GUI** on a telecom. device?

Which of the options suits my scenario? 
I have been following Qt's blogs about these related topics. Still not sure which method is suitable?

Sorry for a lengthy explanation. Kindly provide some suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Try checking out this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-network.html, maybe it helps you find a solution that suits your needs.

Comment: The examples in that link are used for same devices(server and client on a single device). Cannot use for communication between an embedded device and a desktop computer. I have already looked into those examples. anyways thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Network communication is general, you can communicate with anything anywhere, e.g. create a socket on one side and a socket on the other side. As long as there is a network connection between the 2, then you can communicate.

Comment: If Qt 5.9.x is a requirement, you are probably left with inventing something yourself.  The technology integration into Qt (like the ones you mention) are all in later versions.  They become options if you update, if not you probably need a custom protocol.